# Xen start hangs on waiting for root file system

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, xen

I'm trying to setup some Xen stuff, and made 4 images, exactly the same, based on the Ubuntu hardy 64 bit system I'm running everything on.

I literally made the images with a bash loop, and they are all exactly the same, named xen{1,2,3,4}.

1, 2, and 3 start just fine, but 4 hangs on waiting for root file system.

Comment: What does `/var/log/xen/xend.log` give you for that domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually in the logs for the xen-create-image command. The disk image didn't get created properly since it was already mounted. I must have CTRL+C'd something and not umount'd the disk. umounting and remaking the domain fixed the problem.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You should accept your own answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Yeah I will...you have to wait a little while to be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark, but have you ran out of loop devices? run "cat /proc/diskstats" to see how many loop devices your kernel can use.

Comment: i see loop0 through loop7, but the problem happens when i run just xen4 on its own